# Compare two lists and return the first element that is in both lists

Tags: haskell

```
  element1 :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
  element1 [] [] = []
  element1 [] _ = []
  element1 _ [] = []

  element1 (h1:t1) (h2:t2) = if
```

I'm Stuck and not sure how to proceed from here, I want to check two lists and return the first element that is in both lists

Comment: You are on your way; you need to return `h1` and `h2` as list.

Comment: You want `intersect´ from Data.List, it would seem?

Answer (score 1):

You can define an auxiliary predicate that checks if an element is in a list (this is already implemented in Data.List). Then in your main function you do recursion over the first list. This is one way to do it.

```
element1 :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
element1 [] _ = []
element1 _ [] = []
element1 (h:t) xs = if   (isInList h xs)
                    then [h]
                    else element1 t xs

isInList :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
isInList _ [] = False
isInList e (x:xs) = if   e == x
                    then True  
                    else isInList e xs
```

Some outputs:

```
element1 [1,2,3] [8,5,9,3] = [3]
element1 [1,2,3] [1,5,9,3] = [1]
element1 [1,2,3] [3,2,1] = [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear, if they should be at the same position or what. Assuming yes:

```
f = ((head . concat) .) . zipWith (\x y -> [x | x == y])
```

Or, expanded:

```
f xs ys = head $ concat $ zipWith (\x y -> [x | x == y]) xs ys
```

If an index must be minimal in the first list:

```
f xs ys = head [x | x <- xs, x `elem` ys]
```

Comment: return the first element in both list but they dont have to be in the same position in both list.

Comment: @theBean, then what does "the first" mean? Should an index of the first be minimal? Or of the second? Or their sum?

Comment: what should `f [1,2] [2,1]` return?